# How to get prompt value in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I want to do is when the user enters a text in the prompt box and presses the OK button, the prompt box will send back the value to `string prmt;` and if they cancelled the prompt, it will do nothing.

Codes:

```
string prmt; 
if(ren>=1)
{

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "prompt", "prompt('Enter your message here.')", true);

//if(ok){}
//if(cancel){}

}
```

Sorry for my grammar.

Comment: Hello, I have edited your answer to ease understanding. For your problem, use a hidden text field that will store the user input, this is easily done with Javascript. OR, use AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I'm not quite popular in JavaScript and Ajax but I will try to search.

Comment: If you give me some time, I will provide you with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this problem, the best solution I can think of would be AJAX, but there is an another way. Create a hidden field in the HTML file like this:

```
<form id="theform" runat="server">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidValue" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Now, the next thing that should be done is to add a JavaScript block to your HTML file. This snippet will get the prompt's value and store it in the hidden field that we had created before. Something like this will probably work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function storeinput(value) {
            document.getElementById("<%=hidValue.ClientID%>").value = value;
        }
</script>
```

This has created a `storeinput` function, which when called will set the hidden field's value to the provided `value` argument. Next thing we need to do is to wire them together with the ASP.NET.
Instead of

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "prompt", "prompt('Enter your message here.')", true);
```

Do this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "prompt", "var value = prompt('Enter your message here.'); storeinput(value);", true);
```

Or something like that (I am not really experienced with ASP.NET, but I guess that will work fine). And after you just simple check the `hidValue` field's value using your favourite ASP.NET way and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank You. Problem solved. The JavaScript must be placed before the form so it will load first.

Comment: Yes, JS is usually placed in the header.