# How to call Yes or No warning box using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, database, code-behind

User enter the data. Then I will check the database whether the data is present or not. If the data is present in the data, then I have ask the user to replace the data or not. Depends on user response the will be replaced or cancelled. How it can be done in asp.net

For example: 
In database for a student name is Ramesh and his mark is 55.
when a teacher entering student detail for a name Ramesh already the data is exist. So now we will ask the user whether old data needs to be replaced or not

Comment: What have you tried so far ? It would be great [to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Kaj Is the above example is sufficient for you

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503447/how-to-get-prompt-value-in-asp-net

Comment: @MihirDave no it is not what I am expecting